# R Performance Analytics not working

Tags: r, xts

I want to use the R performance analytics on my data. I get the data from the database and it looks like this:

```
PnL<-GetDRWPnLByDesk("Entity A") # this gets the data from the database
head(PnL)
```

Here is what the data looks like:

```
businessdate     PnL
1   2014-01-01     40.39
2   2014-01-02   48.42
3   2014-01-03    17.00
4   2014-01-06  -925.71
5   2014-01-07 -1020.52
```

Here are the classes of my 2 columns

> class(PnL$businessdate)
>           [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

```
> class(PnL$PnL) [1] "numeric"
```

Now I want to use the charts.PerformanceSummary() function so I create a time series object and try to use it:

```
 PnL_TS <- xts(PnL$PnL, order.by=as.Date(PnL$businessdate, format="%Y%m%d"))
charts.PerformanceSummary(PnL_TS)
```

But I get an error:
Error in ts(PnL$PnL, start = min(PnL$businessdate), end = max(PnL$businessdate)) : 
  invalid time series parameters specified

Any ideas how to fix it?

thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged SAS?

Comment: It was an error I removed the SAS tag.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of your vector `PnL_TS`.... `charts.PerformanceSummary(x)` 
`x : an xts, vector, matrix, data frame, timeSeries or zoo object of asset returns`

```
PnL_TS <- ROC(PnL_TS) # convert to log returns
charts.PerformanceSummary(PnL_TS) # plot
```